# Sort Table with PHP but no sort by number

Tags: php, sql

I want to create database, all I need is perfect (adding data, edit, and delete) in php. I just learn php yesterday but my teacher give me task that is crazy bcz deadline is tonight. My database table cannot sorted by number after adding data :( I create this using xampp and notepad ++, please help me for fix the result that is sorted the result after adding data on the table...

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>Data Perikanan TPI Pondokdadap, Sendangbiru, Malang</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$sambung = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Gagal konek ke server.");
mysql_select_db("data_ikan") or die ("Gagal membuka database.");
?>
<table border="3">
 </select>
<tr>
<th>Nomor</th>
<th>Tanggal Input</th>
<th>Pukul</th>
<th>Nama Kapal</th>
<th>Nama Nelayan</th>
<th>Bobot Tangkapan</th>
<th>Jenis Tangkapan</th>
<th>Nama Penginput</th>
<th colspan="3">Aksi</th>
</tr>
<?php
$query = "select * from ikan";
$result = mysql_query($query, $sambung);
//$no = 0;
while ($buff = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
//$no++;
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $buff['nomor']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $buff['tanggal']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $buff['pukul']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $buff['namakapal']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $buff['namanelayan']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $buff['bobottangkapan']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $buff['jenistangkapan']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $buff['namapenginput']; ?></td>
<td><a href="edit.php?nomor=<?php echo $buff['nomor']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="hapus.php?nomor=<?php echo $buff['nomor']; ?>">Hapus</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
mysql_close($sambung);
?>
</table>
<p align="left"><a href="tambah.html">Tambah Data</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...and the problem is?  Note that in SQL, unless the `ORDER BY` clause is specified, the db returns rows in whatever order it feels like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sorting-rows.html) clause to sort data. Change

```
$query = "select * from ikan";
```

to

```
$query = "select * from ikan order by nomor";
```

Or with direction specified:

```
$query = "select * from ikan order by nomor asc";
$query = "select * from ikan order by nomor desc";
```

Comment: thank you very much :)  Sorry if i dont do research because I just learn this yesterday and I stressed of deadline :(